# DIsk Performance Counters not available remotely

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-server-2016, performance-counters

The Physical Disk performance counters of a Windows Server 2016 are present and available **locally**, but **not remotely**. I've tried many suggestions out there such as checking registry, lodctr /r and restart relevant services but nothing helps. What could be the cause?

On the client machine in Performance Monitor, the section for Physical Disk does not show for the remote machine, while they do so locally on the target machine itself.

Equally `Powershell > Get-Counter -ListSet physicaldisk -ComputerName mycomputer` succeeds locally but fails remotely with

```
Get-Counter : Cannot find any performance counter sets on the mycomputer computer that match the following: physicaldisk.
At line:1 char:2
+  Get-Counter -ListSet physicaldisk -ComputerName mycomputer
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingCounterSetsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

I'm at a loss. Please don't suggest rebooting the machine, I want to solve this without rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case, I had to re-register the system performance libraries with WMI (`winmgmt /resyncperf`) and reboot the machine. Restarting services was not enough.

Here is what helped me to see my `physicaldisk` perfctrs again:

```
diskperf -y          # Enable diskperf at boot
lodctr /R            # Restore perfctr registry settings
timeout 10           # Wait 10s
winmgmt /resyncperf  # Reset WMI perfctrs
shutdown /r /f /t 0  # Reboot
```